# changing Sub Query to Join condition

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012, subquery, sql-server-2014

can anyone help me to modify the below sub query into Join Condition so that we can improve the performance of the script

```
   from   #Head         hw
      join   Employee           et
        on   hw.EmployeeCode    = et.EmployeeCode
       and   et.BonusFlag       = 1
      join   Bonus           cb
        on   hw.BonusId             = cb.BonusId 
        and  cb.CompanyId           = @CompanyId
      join   bonus b
        on   hw.BonusId             = b.BonusId 
      join   Expense     pr
        on   pr.CompanyId           = @CompanyId
       and   pr.ModuleId         = b.ModuleId   
     Where   hw.BucketId        =  @BucketId
       and   upper (et.EmployeeCode)     <> 'H'
       and   hw.bucketcode not in (Select centercode from NExclusion)
```

Comment: Please learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit `JOIN`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
from #Head hw
  join NExclusion on NExclusion.centercode = hw.bucketcode
  join Employee et on hw.EmployeeCode = et.EmployeeCode
  join Bonus b on hw.BonusId = b.BonusId 
  join Expense pr on pr.CompanyId = @CompanyId and pr.ModuleId = b.ModuleId 
  Where hw.BucketId = @BucketId and et.BonusFlag = 1 and b.CompanyId = @CompanyId and et.EmployeeCode <> 'h'
```

I made the following changes:
1) Moved all conditions to one place in the last after where clause.
2) Sql is not case sensitive so you don't need to convert EmployeeCode to upper case and compare, I have removed that to reduce this performance overhead.
3) Changed the IN condition to join.
4) Removed the duplicate join with Bonus table